# Updating configurable product throws Integrity constraint violation error about UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have the following script which uses Magento models to create or update a configurable product.

```
// Method to create or update configurable product with configurable options
function createOrUpdateConfigurableProduct($product_data, $configurable_products_data)
{
    // Init product
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    // Load product id by sky
    $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getIdBySku($product_data['sku']);

    // If product already exists
    if ($product_id)
    {
        // Load product
        $product->load($product_id);
    }

    // Set product data
    $product
        ->setTypeId('configurable')
        ->setAttributeSetId(4)
        ->setSku($product_data['sku'])
        ->setName($product_data['name'])
        ->setDescription($product_data['description'])
        ->setShortDescription($product_data['description'])
        ->setMetaTitle($product_data['name'])
        ->setMetaDescription($product_data['description'])
        ->setPrice($product_data['price'])
        ->setTaxClassId(2)
        ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
        ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
            'manage_stock'            => 1,
            'is_in_stock'             => ($product_data['qty'] >= 1 ? 1 : 0)
        ));

    // Workout all the attribute ids used
    $used_attribute_ids = array();
    foreach ($configurable_products_data as $product_id => $options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if (!in_array($option['attribute_id'], $used_attribute_ids)) {
                $used_attribute_ids[] = $option['attribute_id'];
            }
        }
    }

    // Set configurable attributes data
    $product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($used_attribute_ids);
    $configurableAttributesData = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

    // Set configurable products data & save
    $product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurable_products_data);
    $product->save();
}
```

Where `$configurable_products_data` looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [49] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 27 in.
                    [attribute_id] => 155
                    [value_index] => 47
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 210
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 32L
                    [attribute_id] => 156
                    [value_index] => 50
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 210
                )

        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 28 in.
                    [attribute_id] => 155
                    [value_index] => 48
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 210
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 32L
                    [attribute_id] => 156
                    [value_index] => 50
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 210
                )

        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 28 in.
                    [attribute_id] => 155
                    [value_index] => 48
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 210
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 34L
                    [attribute_id] => 156
                    [value_index] => 51
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 210
                )

        )

)
```

When this code runs, on first run - it work's fine and create the configurable product. However, on the second run, it doesn't seem to be able to update existing configurable product, it's throwing the following cryptic error message:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '52-155' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID''

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i use this code to insert and update configurable product in my custom extension.

where all data get in data variable

$pid is configurable product id.
$aid is attribute id.
before you use this code u set session variable is edit to 0 or 1. 0- if new product , 1- if edit existing product

```
$data = $this->getRequest ()->getPost();
            $pid=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getAttributeId();
            $aid=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getAttributeValue();
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $prd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
            try
            {
                $totalRow=count($data['product_id']);
                if($totalRow>0)
                {
                         $configurable = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
                         if(!Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsEdit(0))
                         {
                            $configurable->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array($aid));
                         }
                         $configurable->save();
                         $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                         $configAttributeCode = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($aid)->getAttributeCode();
                         $simpleProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                                ->addIdFilter($data['product_id'])
                                ->addAttributeToSelect($configAttributeCode);

                         $configurableProductsData = array();
                         $configurableAttributesData = $configurable->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();

                            for($l=0;$l<$totalRow;$l++)
                            {
                                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($data['product_id'][$l]);
                                $_product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
                                $_product->getResource()->save($_product);
                                $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                                $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($aid);
                                $att_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($data['attribute_type'][$l]);
                                $productData = array( 
                                        'label' => $att_label, //attribute label
                                        'attribute_id' => $aid, //attribute ID 
                                        'value_index' => $data['attribute_type'][$l],
                                        'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
                                        'pricing_value' => $data['product_price'][$l] //value for the pricing
                                );
                                $configurableProductsData[$_product->getId()] = $productData;
                                $configurableAttributesData[0]['values'][$l] = $productData;
                            }

                            $configurable->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
                            $configurable->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
                            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
                            $configurable->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
                            $configurable->setStatus(1);
                            $configurable->save();

                }
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();  
            }
```